# How do I create this graph in LaTeX?

Tags: graphs, tikz-graphs

I was wondering how I would be able to create this complete graph (K4) in LaTeX, with the edges colored either blue or red based on what's shown.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: If you want to make graphs as simple as this, use TikZ. There's a `graph-drawing` library in case you need something more complex

Comment: Did you have a look at the TikZ documentation or do you have a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to start with?

Comment: There are many examples of this type, e.g. `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path foreach \X in {1,...,4}
  { (-45+90*\X:1) node[circle,fill=green!70!black,inner sep=1ex] (c\X){}
  } foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(Mod(\X+2,4)+1)}] in {1,...,4}
  {\ifodd\X
    (c\X) edge[red] (c\Y)
   \else
    (c\X) edge[cyan] (c\Y)
   \fi}
   (c2) edge[red] (c4) (c1) edge[cyan] (c3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` will do. However, likely you will have something more general in mind which you may want to explain.

Answer (score 3):

A fast solution with Mathcha :-).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1, line width=1mm]   (187,229) -- (364,229) ;
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1, line width=1mm]   (364,52) -- (187,229) ;
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1, line width=1mm]   (187,52) -- (364,52) ;
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1, line width=1mm]   (364,52) -- (364,229) ;
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1, line width=1mm  ]   (187,52) -- (364,229) ;
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1, line width=1mm  ]   (187,52) -- (187,229) ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp03642722858449887] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (173.5,52) .. controls (173.5,44.54) and (179.54,38.5) .. (187,38.5) .. controls (194.46,38.5) and (200.5,44.54) .. (200.5,52) .. controls (200.5,59.46) and (194.46,65.5) .. (187,65.5) .. controls (179.54,65.5) and (173.5,59.46) .. (173.5,52) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp5110077705683167] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (350.5,52) .. controls (350.5,44.54) and (356.54,38.5) .. (364,38.5) .. controls (371.46,38.5) and (377.5,44.54) .. (377.5,52) .. controls (377.5,59.46) and (371.46,65.5) .. (364,65.5) .. controls (356.54,65.5) and (350.5,59.46) .. (350.5,52) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp42972232221333573] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (350.5,229) .. controls (350.5,221.54) and (356.54,215.5) .. (364,215.5) .. controls (371.46,215.5) and (377.5,221.54) .. (377.5,229) .. controls (377.5,236.46) and (371.46,242.5) .. (364,242.5) .. controls (356.54,242.5) and (350.5,236.46) .. (350.5,229) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp7505367984521332] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (173.5,229) .. controls (173.5,221.54) and (179.54,215.5) .. (187,215.5) .. controls (194.46,215.5) and (200.5,221.54) .. (200.5,229) .. controls (200.5,236.46) and (194.46,242.5) .. (187,242.5) .. controls (179.54,242.5) and (173.5,236.46) .. (173.5,229) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
 \usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

 \[ \psset{arrows=-, linewidth=0.6pt, nodesep=0pt, dotsize=4.5pt, rowsep=1.2cm, colsep = 1.5cm, shortput =tablr}
 \begin{psmatrix}[emnode=dot, linecolor=MediumSeaGreen]
  & & \\%
  & & 
  %%%
\psset{linecolor=DeepSkyBlue}
 \ncline{1,1}{1,2} \ncline{2,1}{2,2} \ncline{2,1}{1,2}
\psset{linecolor=Coral}
\ncline{1,1}{2,1}\ncline{1,2}{2,2}\ncline{1,1}{2,2}
 \end{psmatrix}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]