# How to Create a Fast Code with TikZ Using MATHCHA

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, mathcha

I have seen many nice Tikz illustrations on this site where it is indicated that the Latex code comes from Mathcha; for example, Sebastiano's answer in

[How to draw simple spring mass system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536042/how-to-draw-simple-spring-mass-system/536049#comment1451591_536049)

where the sketch given in the question
[image]

is answered with

[image]

and prefaced with the statement---

``If you like the drawing...you can create a fast code with TikZ using Matcha:''

I have seen many other posts referencing Mathcha, such as, to name a few---

[How to Draw a Rose in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570484/how-to-draw-a-rose-in-latex/570516#570516)

[How do I create this graph in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543260/how-do-i-create-this-graph-in-latex/543277#543277)

[Is it possible to draw a curve like the given?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555291/is-it-possible-to-draw-a-curve-like-the-given/576484#576484)

MY QUESTION IS:  How does one bring an image (such as the mass/spring sketch) over to https://www.mathcha.io and then produce image given by Sebastiano with the accompanying Latex code?

I have not been able to figure this out.

If someone familiar with the Mathcha site can provide a set of step-by-step instructions to go from a sketch to the Latex code, I would be grateful for the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm the crazy author **:-)** of the some answers done with Mathcha that I export in `TikZ`.

But it is important to know that this way that I adopt it is not very correct.

It is necessary to know the pure `TikZ` and to write a correct code using the mind. I like to draw and I thought that, considering that there are many users who ask for very complicated drawings without an example, an minimal working example, it is right that those who like to draw like me, learn a beautiful tool that is `Mathcha`.

Mathcha has a very big problem in that he is not registered or logged in. If you create a drawing, export it to TikZ, and then close everyone out, you won't be able to recreate the same drawing unless you have minimal TikZ skills.

The tool is simple to use but it requires creativity, passion and a lot of craftiness.

[image]

When you go to the site go to the bottom, close the initial instructions and accept. Then delete the whole page by selecting it (nr. 1) and then click on drawing area (nr. 2). Clicking on it you will find all the commands for drawing (nr. 3).

[image]

Then draw an arrow (nr. 4), for example, and export the code to `TikZ` (nr. 5)
[image].

[image]

That's all it is.

*I would like to point out once again that my method is wrong, but it is only a quick way to create code done in TikZ.*

Comment: @SamuelBowditch :-)...I am and also the other users are avaliable with you and other. All the best.