# Tikzpicture visual editor

Tags: tikz-pgf, editors

I am drawing tables such as this one:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.5]
\node at (3,-1.5) { text1 };
\node at (1,-3.5) { text2 };

\node at (-0.2,-0.1) {  };
\node at (-0.2,-0.85) {  };
\node at (-0.2,-1.85) {  };
\node at (-0.2,-2.85) { more text };
\node at (-0.2,-3.85) {  };
\node at (-0.2,-4.85) {  };

\node at (0.15,0.2) {  };
\node at (0.85,0.2) { };
\node at (1.85,0.2) { more text };

\node at (1.85,-2.85) { more text };

\node at (3.85,0.2) { };

\draw (0,0) -- (0,-5);
\draw (0,-5) -- (4,-5);
\draw (4,-5) -- (4,0);
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw (0,0) -- (0,-1);
\draw (0,-1) -- (1,-1);
\draw (1,-1) -- (1,-2);
\draw (1,-2) -- (2,-2);
\draw (2,-2) -- (2,-3);
\draw (2,-3) -- (3,-3);
\draw (3,-3) -- (3,-4);
\draw (3,-4) -- (4,-4);
\draw (4,-4) -- (4,-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Now I even want to make rows and columns and shadow certain parts of the resulting grid.

I was wondering if there is some tool that allows me to do this visually and gives me the tikzpicture code back. I used [this one](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/) for graphs but it does not seem to support tikzpicture.

Comment: I think that if you use a visual editor the best thing is to save in SVG or whatever and then import it --- Ti*k*Z strength is the integration you can achieve. But you can try matcha: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/576516/38080

Comment: I think that for this kind of drawing you can use [Ti*k*Z matrix library](https://tikz.dev/library-matrix)  or maybe even the package [`nicematrix`](https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix?lang=en) instead of manually draw everything.